# Multi-Part Identifier could not be bound - Moving column and data to different table

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Contract as CaseRef, DateTime, Username 
INTO #tempDB 
FROM callhandlinginfo

INSERT INTO CallHandlingInfo(Event)
    SELECT(Event)
    FROM tblComplianceData 
    WHERE tblComplianceData.CaseRef = #tempdb.CaseRef

SELECT * FROM CallHandlingInfo
```

I get error

> Multi-Part Identifier could not be bound.

Thanks all for the response, I see my mistake! What would it look like if it were an `UPDATE` statement instead?

Comment: The second query (`INSERT INTO CallHandlingInfo(Event) ....`) doesn't reference the `#tempDB` table in any way, shape or form - therefore, you cannot reference it in the `WHERE` clause ...

Comment: So how do I go about referring to this column?

Comment: @MitchelStuartFountaine . . . It is totally unclear what you want to do.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: What would it look like if it were an UPDATE Statement instead?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess on what you want to accomplish is:

```
INSERT INTO CallHandlingInfo(Event)
    SELECT Event
    FROM tblComplianceData cd
    WHERE cd.CaseRef IN (SELECT cr.CaseRef FROM #tempdb.CaseRef cr);
```

You might want an update.  Assuming SQL Server, it might look like this:

```
update chi
    set event = cd.event
    from callhandlinginfo chi join
         tblComplianceData cd
         on cd.CaseRef = chi.CaseRef;
```

Comment: Thanks! What would it look like if it were an UPDATE Statement instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow **reference** that `#tempDB` table in your second query - either by using a `JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO CallHandlingInfo(Event)
    SELECT Event
    FROM dbo.tblComplianceData 
    INNER JOIN #tempDB ON tblComplianceData.CaseRef = #tempdb.CaseRef
```

(*not sure if you really want an `INNER JOIN` - that totally depends on your requirements, which we don't know about...*)

or by using something like `IN`:

```
INSERT INTO CallHandlingInfo(Event)
    SELECT Event
    FROM dbo.tblComplianceData 
    WHERE tblComplianceData.CaseRef IN (SELECT CaseRef FROM #tempdb)
```